# Unable to view the data in the datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, wrapper-class

I am trying to display the contact record's Name, Phone & Email field on a datatable by bringing the value dynamically from custom metadata records but when I am adding the component on the page the columns are appearing but the data is not loaded on the datatable.

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class ContactController {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Contact> geContacts(){
    try {
        return [SELECT ID, Name, Phone, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 10];

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<ColumnsWrapper> getDataTableColumns(){
        List<ColumnsWrapper> listColumnAttributes = new List<ColumnsWrapper>();
        for(Dynamic_Columns__mdt columnsObj : [SELECT fieldName__c, label__c, type__c FROM Dynamic_Columns__mdt]){
            ColumnsWrapper wrapperObj = new ColumnsWrapper();
             wrapperObj.label = columnsObj.label__c;
             wrapperObj.fieldName = columnsObj.fieldName__c;
             wrapperObj.type = columnsObj.type__c;
            listColumnAttributes.add(wrapperObj);
        }
            return listColumnAttributes;
}

public class ColumnsWrapper{

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldName{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String type{get; set;}
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Datatable with configurable columns">
    <lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
                         data={data}
                         columns={columns}
                         is-loading="true"
                         >
    </lightning-datatable>
</lightning-card>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.geContacts';
import getTableAttributes from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getDataTableColumns';

export default class DynamicDatatable extends LightningElement {

    columns = [];
    data={};

    @wire(getContacts)
    contacts({ data, error }) {
        if (data){
            this.data = [...data];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }

    @wire(getTableAttributes)
    tableValues({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.columns = [...data];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.columns));
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

**Component:**

[image]

Comment: Make sure your metadata records matches with the fields you're retrieving from the SOQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data tables iterate over Arrays, not Objects.

The following line of code...

```
this.data = {...data};
```

...ends up changing the Array you returned into an Object, where each key is the index array:

```
{ '0': { ... }, '1': { ... }, ... }
```

You can't iterate over Objects in LWC, so this does nothing.

Instead, change the code to:

```
this.data = [...data];
```

Comment: Tried this @sfdcfox but the values are not getting displayed. It is showing blank rows. Updated the answer.

Comment: @code234 Check your metadata. JavaScript is case sensitive, so if fieldName doesn't match, it would cause the problem you've described.

Comment: You were right fieldName was small case. Thank you!

Comment: @code234 Yeah, no problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: @code234 I would also add, in you LWC controller, you're defining the data as an **Object** (`data = {}`), rather than that, you would want to define it as an **Array** (`data = []`), because of consistency, also you could make use of a variable in the LWC controller (`isLoading = true;`) and use it in the template for the _is-loading_ property. Also I believe that assigning `this.data = [...data]` is not necessary, you could just simply assign it `this.data = data` I'm not sure how to explain why but I believe I'm correct @sfdcfox what do you think?

Comment: @AjFmO Yes, all good suggestions. For the last statement, the explanation is that we don't need to copy the data because we are not mutating (changing) the data. In fact, unless we need to do any work at all, we don't need the handler itself, it can just be a property, as in `@wire(getContacts) contacts` and in the markup `data={contacts.data}`.